# How to get percentage of CPU usage of OS from java

Tags: java, jmx

I want to calculate percentage of CPU usage of OS from java code.

1. There are several ways to find it by `unix` command [e.g. using `mpstat`, `/proc/stat` etc...] and use it from `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

But I don't want to use the system calls.

I tried `ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()`

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean =
         (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println(osBean.getSystemLoadAverage());
```

But it gives the cpu load but not the cpu usage. Is there anyway to find the usage percentage?

Comment: Can you link to Javadoc for the `OperatingSystemMXBean` please? Is percentage calculated from load or vice versa? I do not know, but it might be.

Comment: No. Load is nothing to do with percentage. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) and [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html)

Answer (score 44):

In Java 7 you can get it like so:

```
public static double getProcessCpuLoad() throws Exception {

    MBeanServer mbs    = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName name    = ObjectName.getInstance("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem");
    AttributeList list = mbs.getAttributes(name, new String[]{ "ProcessCpuLoad" });

    if (list.isEmpty())     return Double.NaN;

    Attribute att = (Attribute)list.get(0);
    Double value  = (Double)att.getValue();

    // usually takes a couple of seconds before we get real values
    if (value == -1.0)      return Double.NaN;
    // returns a percentage value with 1 decimal point precision
    return ((int)(value * 1000) / 10.0);
}
```

Comment: Does this only work on certain operating systems? Running Java 7u15 on 64bit Windows 7, `NaN` is returned, as `value` is negative one.

Comment: It should work on all.  I tested it on Window 7 Java7u51 64bit and it works fine after a few seconds.  The first few seconds return -1.0 because it takes some time to initialize some of the objects/values.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to take about one second on my machine for the CPU load to be an actual value. Thanks for the clarification. +1

Comment: I added a comment in the code to clarify for future users who might not read the comments here.

Comment: @Igal thank you for the answer. I am using windows-7 + java 7u45 but still no luck for me. By the way, the attribute list you provided in code is `ProcessCpuLoad`. Is it the CPU load or CPU usage?

Comment: ProcessCpuLoad is the % CPU load of that JVM for the system.  there is also SystemCpuLoad which gives the load of the whole system.  did you try to call it in a loop?  I noticed that the first few calls return -1.0

Comment: It always returns NaN in Mac OS X, even after several minutes.

Comment: This one worked like a charm ! I cross checked with jconsole and they gave similar value (more or less),

Comment: (value * 1000) / 10.0) == value * 100

Comment: @Raheel actually, not.  by dividing by `10.0` you convert the `int` to `double`.

Comment: You would realize this when you calculate these stats... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SIGAR API](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home). 
It is cross platform ( but I've only use it on Windows).

The Javadoc is available [here](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/) and the binaries are [here](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home#Home-binaries)

It is licensed under the terms of the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: Thanks! But in javadoc of this API I see only "Get the Total system cpu time" not the usage under in Cpu class. Can you please guide me where i can get the CPU usage?

Comment: If you have downloaded Sigar from SourceForge, you should find several examples availables at hyperic-sigar-1.6.4\bindings\java\examples\. I think that CpuInfo.java or Top.java could be what you are looking for.

Comment: It seems like nothing later than Ubuntu 9 is certified for SIGAR API as per the site. Should that be a problem?

Comment: we need to take into account of SIGAR making JVM crash also. Strict NO NO for production environment .

Comment: The SIGAR link is dead. Is the project dead as well? Or perhaps acquired by vmware, judging by the second link